# Delete [virtual-file] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

I just came over a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235491/how-to-make-a-virtual-file-in-php) with the [virtual-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-file) tag. It only have 13 questions as of now and I feel there aren't a strong enough link between these questions to justify the tags continued existece. Should it be deleted?

Comment: The virtual-file is a lie.