# [virtual]ly useless catch-all tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

It seems the best approach is to retag anything with [virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual) to one of the following, more specific tags:

1. [virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) or even [virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualization).
2. [virtual-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-file) but this [might be useless](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272999/1739000) as well.
3. [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality)
4. [virtual-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-memory)
5. [virtual-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-method)

This is less of a burninate request and more a request in help retagging these (though I'll get to work on the ones I can).

Comment: Please don't flood the review queue .... :)

Comment: [virtual]ly any tag would be better than this.

Comment: As explained in [a similar tag discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275553/inconsistent-use-of-virtual-on-c-questions), the tag wiki doesn't even hide the fact that it's extremely ambiguous.